# Whats the difference between tiles:insertTemplate and tiles:insertDefinition

Tags: tiles2

tiles:insertDefinition and tiles:insertTemplate both has putAttribute , i am not understanding the difference between the two.I am using tiles 2.x version.

thanks in advance

kranthi

Answer (score 2):

A template is a view which expects to be supplied attributes while definitions are named instances of a template defined in tiles.xml (or pragmatically using the API).

[tiles:insertDefinition](http://tiles.apache.org/2.0/framework/tiles-jsp/tagreference.html#tiles%3ainsertTemplate) requires the name attribue to be set, because you are inserting a defintion you have layed out in tiles.xml.

[tiles:insertTemplate](http://tiles.apache.org/2.0/framework/tiles-jsp/tagreference.html#tiles%3ainsertTemplate) creates a new definition on the spot, from a view and expects you to insert values at that point. It requires the template parameter be set, there is no name attribute.

In general I don't think you should need to use either of these tags often (you can create tiles using applications without ever using either). Avoiding their use means having all definitions clearly laid out one place AND being able to see how all definitions fit together.

This central view is tiles greatest strength which these tags can undermine.

tiles:insertDefinition still means using named definitions, there is still one central location were all layout is controlled but because we are inserting the definition within a view we loose our overview of how everything fits together.

tiles:insertTemplate is akin to a JSP include, you are creating a new definition at that moment in the view and use it. This tile is not part of the overarching view.

In case the argument was not clear, JSP includes can achieve the same reduction in boiler plate code as Tiles can. It is the overarching view which tiles provides that allow you to easily change page structure across the whole application easily. Carefully consider that this is not being undermined.

Comment: This description is per tiles 2.0, since then both tags now can take a "template" parameter and so there is very little difference between the two now.